# Scheme over S and morphisms

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Quoting from Hartshorne

> Let $S$ be a fixed scheme. A *scheme over* $S$ is a scheme $X$, together with a morphism $X \to S$. If $X$ and $Y$ are schemes over $S$, a morphism of $X$ to $Y$ as schemes over $S$, (also called an $S$ morphism ) is a morphism $X \to Y$ which is compatible with the given morphisms to $S$.

There are two things I don't understand.
a) What is meant by "morphism $X \to Y$ which is compatible with the given morphisms to $S$". I don't understand what condition needs to be satisfied for the required compatibility. Can anyone please tell me what actual conditions (in terms of maps) are required to be satisfied?

b)What is the intuition behind this definition ?

Comment: c) Have you looked at any other book on algebraic geometry? The answers are spelled out in detail everywhere.

Comment: There are three maps in sight and they form a diagram; the diagram should commute. Maybe think about varieties over a field $k$ and connect that back to Chapter I: the field is fixed [working over $k = \mathbb{C}$ we didn't allow conjugation, for example], and algebraically all homomorphisms are of $k$-algebras. It gets more interesting than this, though.

Comment: Dear Grobber, I don't think you need to be sorry for your question. This "relative view" of schemes is a rather new idea that originated in conjunction with scheme theory itself. Personally, I don't think it should be obvious to a beginner in algebraic geometry that it is useful.

Comment: @Grobber Consider for all complex numbers $t$ the conic $x^2 + y^2 = tz^2$. You have probably a good idea of how these conics look like for all small enough real numbers $t$. For $t=0$, you get the union of two lines (namely, $x+iy =0$ and $x-iy = 0$). It was an important innovation of Grothendieck to realize this intuitive picture in the category of schemes as the relative morphism   $X =$ Proj$(R[x,y,z]/(x^2 + y^2 - tz^2])\to$ Spec $R = S$, where $R$ is a ring and $t$ is an element of $R$. (In the example: $R$ would correspond to $\mathbb C[t]$.)

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Is there a specific book you had in mind?

Comment: Perhaps it's because my background is closer to differential geometry and I'm a nerd in this subject but... isn't bundles over a manifold the first thing which comes to your mind? If schemes are gonna play the role of manifolds well, there you have. Might I be missing something? PS: your comments about killing morphisms are much more interesting for practical purposes, but in my opinion too sophisticated for beginners.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's one motivation. Suppose you want to do "geometry." By this I mean you are working with varieties over an algebraically closed field, say $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$. By working in the category of schemes over $S=Spec(\overline{\mathbb{Q}})$ you kill off all sorts of morphisms that aren't "coming from geometry." We'll get to what that means after an example.

If we are honestly doing geometry, then we would expect that since $S$ is just geometrically a single point that it's automorphism group would be trivial. But consider any $\sigma\in Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$. As long as $\sigma$ is not the identity map, we get a non-trivial automorphism after applying Spec which we'll call the same thing $\sigma: S\to S$. Thus $Aut(S)$ contains at least the enormous group $Gal(\overline{\mathbb{Q}}/\mathbb{Q})$ (it is in fact equal to this).

This is hardly what we would like to call morphisms coming from geometry. This is what happens when we just work in terms of (non-relative) schemes. We seem to pick up all sorts of morphisms coming from number theoretic or arithmetic sources. Now let's consider $S$ as a scheme over $S$ with the trivial strucutre map $id_S: S\to S$.

Now if we check whether or not any non-trivial $\sigma: S\to S$ is in the automorphism group of $S$ as an $S$-scheme we see it can't be because the appropriate diagram will not commute. In the category of $S$-schemes we see that we actually kill off all the non-geometric automorphisms and $Aut_S(S)$ is just the single identity map we thought we should get.

At first, it looks like considering this more complicated category will make things ... more complicated, but in practice we usual do exactly the situation above. If $X, Y$ are varieties over $k=\overline{k}$, then we work in the category of $k$-schemes. It will simplify things by killing off the non-geometric morphisms.

Comment: Just for those like me who hadn't seen the term "structure morphism" before. The question and answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/839026/what-is-meant-by-a-structure-map) give more details. Then your example about the S-scheme over itself becomes lighting.

Answer (score 1):

For a ring with a morphism from $R$, you can identify the underlying set of the image of $R$ with $R$-elements. Furthermore, by considering only arrows that form commutative triangles from $R$, you impose a cross-ring convention for identifying elements with one another. Likewise, you can identify points of a scheme over $S$ with the points they map to on $S$, and this convention will hold globally if morphisms of schemes over $S$ are required to commute with the arrows to $S$ from the domain and codomain.

These are called the categories of rings under $R$, or $R$-algebras, and schemes over $S$, and are examples of a generic construction in category theory called an arrow category. It helps clarify how a morphism is supposed to know which arrows to commute with to treat the category's objects as the morphisms from $R$ or to $S$ themselves, not the rings or schemes.